# Reference error on Google's Firebase authentication tutorial project

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have been working through the [Google Firebase Authentication tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/authenticating-users). Everything in the project worked up until this point and I have basically done a direct copy and paste from their github for the files.  The two files related to my problem are:

1. [static.js](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/d54fb83118e5ce95d928119b10f5b07a9b13d018/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app/building-an-app-3/static/script.js)
2. [index.html](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app/building-an-app-3/templates/index.html)

For the static.js file the only changes I have made are to remove some comments for the purposes of brevity for this question.  The is shown here (I do not believe this file is the problem):

```
//static.js
'use strict';

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementById('sign-out').onclick = function () {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  };

  // FirebaseUI config.
  var uiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '/',
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    // Terms of service url.
    tosUrl: '<your-tos-url>'
  };

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in, so display the "sign out" button and login info.
      document.getElementById('sign-out').hidden = false;
      document.getElementById('login-info').hidden = false;
      console.log(`Signed in as ${user.displayName} (${user.email})`);
      user.getIdToken().then(function (token) {
        document.cookie = "token=" + token;
      });
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
      var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
      // Show the Firebase login button.
      ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
      // Update the login state indicators.
      document.getElementById('sign-out').hidden = true;
      document.getElementById('login-info').hidden = true;
      // Clear the token cookie.
      document.cookie = "token=";
    }
  }, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('Unable to log in: ' + error)
  });
});
```

In my index.html I have inserted the code coped from the firebase console with the "CDN" option selected.  Note that I have left in the comments in the code copied from Google incase they are useful.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Datastore and Firebase Auth Example</title>

  <!-- See https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web. -->
  <!-- [START gae_python38_auth_init_firebase] -->
  <!-- [START gae_python3_auth_init_firebase] -->

  <!-- THIS IS WHAT I COPIED AND PASTED IN -->
  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "A****************Q",
      authDomain: "c*******.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "c*******",
      storageBucket: "c*******.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1**********0",
      appId: "1:1**********10:web:0**********53",
      measurementId: "G-1********S"
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>
  <!-- END OF WHAT I COPIED AND PASTED IN -->
  <!-- [END gae_python3_auth_init_firebase] -->
  <!-- [END gae_python38_auth_init_firebase] -->
  <script>
    if (typeof firebase === 'undefined') {
      const msg = "Please paste the Firebase initialization snippet into index.html. See https://console.firebase.google.com > Overview > Add Firebase to your web app.";
      console.log(msg);
      alert(msg);
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <!-- [START gae_python38_auth_include_firebaseui] -->
  <!-- [START gae_python3_auth_include_firebaseui] -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.4.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
  <!-- [END gae_python3_auth_include_firebaseui] -->
  <!-- [END gae_python38_auth_include_firebaseui] -->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

</head>
<body>

<h1>Datastore and Firebase Auth Example</h1>

<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>

<button id="sign-out" hidden=true>Sign Out</button>

<div id="login-info" hidden=true>
  <h2>Login info:</h2>
  {% if user_data %}
    <dl>
      <dt>Name</dt><dd>{{ user_data['name'] }}</dd>
      <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{ user_data['email'] }}</dd>
      <dt>Last 10 visits</dt><dd>
    {% for time in times %}
          <p>{{ time['timestamp'] }}</p>
        {% endfor %} </dd>
    </dl>
  {% elif error_message %}
    <p>Error: {{ error_message }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this either on local host or while deployed I trigger the console.log message that tells me I need to add Firebase.  In the console I also receive the following errors:

```
exports_auth.js:801 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'INTERNAL')
    at li (utils.js:681)
    at new Ri (utils.js:1225)
    at rpchandler.js:371
    at exports_auth.js:801
    at exports_auth.js:801
    at firebase-auth.js:1
    at firebase-auth.js:1
exports_auth.js:801 Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate firebase-auth.js - be sure to load firebase-app.js first.
    at exports_auth.js:801
    at firebase-auth.js:1
    at firebase-auth.js:11
script.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at script.js:12
```

My assumptions are that I either copy/pasted into wrong spot or that I need to have a bunch of CDN src's imported but I have tried about every combination I can think of. Any help appreciated.

Note: If it makes any difference, backend is flask, exactly copied and pasted from tutorial as shown in [main.py.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app/building-an-app-3/main.py)

Comment: If anybody ever works this out (I haven't yet) you should leave some breadcrumbs over here, where somebody else had the same problem:

https://teratail.com/questions/376000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong - the documentation is out of date (I think as a result of Firebase 9 changes). I doubt this is very helpful 14 months later, but leaving the fix here for anybody who stumbles on this via Google.

`main.py` and `script.js` are fine as at [this commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/234c2cdc66d552f7c40d70ee3db2c21ffec50825/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app/building-an-app-3), but `index.html` needs an update. A modern Firebase snippet is going to end like this:

```
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

but you'll need to change it to this (or update a heap of refs in the tutorial):

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

You also need to add this script:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
```

and move the `typeof firebase === 'undefined'` block further down (or just delete it).

Putting it all together, this version of index.html will work with all the other tutorial files - I've also reorganized the imports and deleted a heap of boilerplate comments. You just need to sub in firebaseConfig from your project as shown in http://console.firebase.google.com.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Datastore and Firebase Auth Example</title>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.13.0/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
    <script>
    const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "--redacted--",
    authDomain: "--redacted--",
    projectId: "--redacted--",
    storageBucket: "--redacted--",
    messagingSenderId: "--redacted--",
    appId: "--redacted--"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Datastore and Firebase Auth Example</h1>

<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>

<button id="sign-out" hidden=true>Sign Out</button>

<div id="login-info" hidden=true>
  <h2>Login info:</h2>
  {% if user_data %}
    <dl>
      <dt>Name</dt><dd>{{ user_data['name'] }}</dd>
      <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{ user_data['email'] }}</dd>
      <dt>Last 10 visits</dt><dd>
    {% for time in times %}
          <p>{{ time['timestamp'] }}</p>
        {% endfor %} </dd>
    </dl>
  {% elif error_message %}
    <p>Error: {{ error_message }}</p>
  {% endif %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```